# Why boost filter_iterator has weird make_filter_iterator function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iterators

after some pain I managed to hack together this minimal example of boost filter_iterator

```
using namespace std;
std::function<bool(uint32_t)> stlfunc= [](uint32_t n){return n%3==0;};
int main()
{
   vector<uint32_t> numbers{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,3,6,9};
   auto start = boost::make_filter_iterator(stlfunc, numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
   auto end   = boost::make_filter_iterator(stlfunc, numbers.end()  , numbers.end());
   auto elem  = std::max_element(start,end);
   cout << *elem;
}
```

It works nice, but I wonder why the make_filter_iterator takes `numbers.end()`?
I might be wrong to use it that way, I guestimated it from the C array example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/example/filter_iterator_example.cpp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is explained in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html):

> When skipping over elements, it is necessary for the filter adaptor to
>   know when to stop so as to avoid going past the end of the underlying
>   range. A filter iterator is therefore constructed with pair of
>   iterators indicating the range of elements in the unfiltered sequence
>   to be traversed.

From the source below you can see the always check if they have reached the end in `satisfy_predicate`:

```
void increment()
{
    ++(this->base_reference());
    satisfy_predicate();
}

void satisfy_predicate()
{
    while (this->base() != this->m_end && !this->m_predicate(*this->base()))
        ++(this->base_reference());
}
```

Also, as pointed out by [Alex Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534180/why-boost-filter-iterator-has-weird-make-filter-iterator-function/15534312#comment22006984_15534312), the
 constructors make it optional when passing the end iterator, for example: `filter_iterator(Iterator x, Iterator end = Iterator());` (provided it is default constructible). So, you could omit `numbers.end()` from your code when constructing the end iterator.

Comment: It also explains that it is optional iff the underlying iterator is default-constructible (and represents the end of the range you want)

Comment: im confused... normal iterators dont know when to stop, so why should filter_iterator do? I mean you dont do for (auto it =v.begin; it !=std::vector<double>::iterator();++it)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Isn't it UB to increment an `end` iterator?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Normal iterators don't skip over elements when incrementing using `++`.

Comment: ok, i get it now... for loop would be broken because for loop  sees iterator after every ++, aka ++ operator doesnt see end, so it would jump over it, and it!=end would never be false

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the declaration of your `make_filter_iterator` template, you see it looks like this:

```
template <class Predicate, class Iterator>
filter_iterator<Predicate,Iterator>
make_filter_iterator(Predicate f, Iterator x, Iterator end = Iterator());
```

Specifically you see that the last parameter is a default parameter, and it's set to `Iterator()` which would mean it's default contructed and for *some types* of iterator it behaves like actual `end()` iterator, which points one past the end of any array, ie it points to garbage.

Most container types do require an actual `end()` iterator to be passed.

Comment: `std::vector<int>::const_iterator() != std::vector<int>::cend()`

Comment: I do not believe there is any guarantee that the standard library container iterators default construct to be equal to the end iterator.

Comment: @DaveS it seems you are correct, I have amended my answer appropriately.